# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim', unable to use model.predict()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, captions

I was trying to make an Image Captioning model in a similar fashion as in [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-a-deep-learning-caption-generation-model-in-python/#comment-437586)

I used ResNet50 instead off VGG16 and also had to use progressive loading via model.fit_generator() method.

I used ResNet50 from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/resnet50.py) and when I imported it by setting include_top = False, It gave me features of photo in shape of {'key': [[[[value1, value2, .... value 2048]]]]}, where "key" is the image id.

Here's my code of caption generator function:-

```
def createCaptions(tokenizer, photoData, MaxLength, model):
    for key, feature in photoData.items():
        inSeq = "START"
        for i in range(MaxLength):
            sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([inSeq])[0]
            sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen = MaxLength)
            ID = model.predict([np.array(feature[0][0][0]), inSeq])
            ID = word_for_id(ID)
            if ID is None:
                break
            inSeq += " " + ID
            if ID == "END":
                break
        print(inSeq)
```

The function word_for_id is :-

```
def word_for_id(integer, tokenizer):
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == integer:
            return word
    return None
```

I had generated photoData via:-

```
features = {}
for images in os.listdir(args["image"]):
    filename = args["image"] + '/' + images
    image = load_img(filename, target_size = inputShape)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)
    image = preprocess(image)
    pred = resnet.predict(image)
    image_id = images.split('.')[0]
    features[image_id] = pred
    print('>{}'.format(images))
```

features is my photoData dictionary.

When I try to generate captions:-

```
caption = createCaptions(tokenizerTrain, features, 34, model)
```

I get the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CaptionGenerator.py", line 111, in <module>
caption = createCaptions(tokenizerTrain, features, 34, model)
  File "CaptionGenerator.py", line 101, in createCaptions
ID = model.predict([np.array(feature[0][0][0]), inSeq])
  File "/home/aditya/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1817, in predict
check_batch_axis=False)
  File "/home/aditya/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 76, in _standardize_input_data
data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
  File "/home/aditya/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
data = [np.expand_dims(x, 1) if x is not None and x.ndim == 1 else x for x in data]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Where did I go wrong?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `inSeq = "START"` to `model.predict` as a string:

```
ID = model.predict([np.array(feature[0][0][0]), inSeq])
```

without pre-processing it. You will need to encode it to an array.

Comment: Thanks for correction:)
One more error arose in my word_for_id function :-
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "CaptionGenerator.py", line 111, in <module>
    caption = createCaptions(tokenizerTrain, features, 36, model)
      File "CaptionGenerator.py", line 102, in createCaptions
    ID = word_for_id(ID, tokenizer)
      File "CaptionGenerator.py", line 90, in word_for_id
    if index == integer:
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
what does this means?

Comment: When I apply if (index == integer).any() in word_for_id function, I only get "START" as the output. Where am I wrong?